# Is there a known bug with ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web app where it does not recognize GetAllAsync method naming convention?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm doing an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC app for the first time, something I know how to do in .NET 4.7.2, and basically I didn't get far as, the very first View I'd normally do for some reason returned blank.

Usually I first create a `GetAllAsync()` method in the controller which returns `View(list)`, and I add a `GetAllAsync.cshtml` view to display it. "Add View" wizard so far always did the basic job fine.

Now the generated page returned blank.

So I did some testing. Made extra methods to check if there are routing issues, played with different view files, different simple methods, redid the whole project as well ... only to get to the bright idea of renaming the `GetAllAsync` method and `GetAllAsync.cshtml` to `Lemon` method and `Lemon.cshtml`, some random term.

And this solved it. As long as I avoid using the naming convention `GetAllAsync`, I don't encounter issues.

But I don't understand why. Does anybody know what is going on?

I've yet to proceed with the CRUD, so I don't know if `Edit`, `Delete`, `Create`, `GetById` and such will behave the same or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 3.0, ASP.NET Core MVC removes the Async suffix from controller action names. Here is the official link: [Async suffix removal from controller action names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#async-suffix-removal-from-controller-action-names)

As for the normal naming of `Edit`, `Delete`, `Create`, `GetById`, it will not be affected. In projects after asp.net core 3.1, as long as the `.cshtml` files are not named with the `Async` ending, you will not encounter the current problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood when you say ASP.NET Core 3.0, ASP.NET Core MVC ... are those two things or one thing? I am using ASP.NET Core 7, but also doing MVC ... so my project is not Core 3.0, but is MVC ... did you want to say any MVC from .NET Core 3 onwards will behave as you explained?

Comment: Hi @yi1fan2, I mean that before ASP.NET Core 3.0 (excluding 3.0), your naming such as GetAllAsync was supported. Starting from 3.0, such naming is not supported. You can click on the blue link in the answer to view the specific official description.